# Return multiple fields using case in select statement of sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table tb3 wherein id,name,sal are to be displayed using a `SELECT` statement and city,descrip fields need to be displayed in the same `SELECT` statement only when the flag is 'Y'. How do I do this using `CASE` statements?

```
      id    name    sal city    descrip flag
       7    john    80000.00    Canada  prog    y
       6    jone    90000.00    NY  test    y
       3    san 70000.00    NY        lead  y
       2    sam 70000.00    Cali    sub n
       1    sally   60000.00    Canada  archi   n
       4    carl    70000.00    SA  plain   n
```

I need to do something like this.. I know it's wrong , but for a sample please have a look..

```
       declare @test varchar(1)
       select @test=flag from tb3
       select id,name,case @test
       when 'Y' then select city,descrip from tb3
       when 'n' then 'inactive'
       end as status from tb3
```

Comment: `varchar(1)` is pointless - it's either 0 or 1 character, but the `var` part adds at least 2 bytes overhead for that. Any string of 5 chars or less ought to be `char(x)` - in your case: `char(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the name of the flag column as following

**Updated:**

```
select id,name ,case flag
when 'Y' then (city +' ' +descrip )
when 'N' then 'inactive'
end as status 
from tb3
```

How can you use @test, because it is varchar(1) variable, it will hold either 'Y' or 'N' which will return only one type of the result. if the last row flag value is 'Y' then all rows will display city,descrip and if last row flag value is 'N' then it will display 'inactive' irrespective of the flag column result for that row.

Comment: Thanks fo the response.I did as you had told. But got an error..'Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: @user1080139, do you want to display the city,descrip as column or the city+' '+descrip will work for you?

Comment: @user1080139, check out this query.

Comment: Is given query fulfills your requirement?

Comment: Wow !! Thank you so much for the help Dude..It works. Alhamdhulillah !

Answer (score 2):

A result set in SQL has a *fixed* set of columns - you can't vary how many columns there are on a row-by-row basis. If you're wanting something that is either the columns `city` and `descrip` or the word `inactive`, then you'll have to join those two columns together into a single value:

```
select id,name,
   CASE WHEN flag='Y' then city + ',' + descrip ELSE 'inactive' END as status
from tb3
```

Or, you can keep them as two columns, and set them as `NULL` when not appropriate:

```
select id,name,
   CASE WHEN flag='Y' then city END as city,
   CASE WHEN flag='Y' then descrip END as descrip
from tb3
```